# Difference between LimitAS and MemoryLimit In Systemd

Tags: systemd

There is a LimitAS which can limit the virtual memory(equivalent to ulimit -v) , but there is also a MemoryLimit(obseleted by MemoryMax in new versions), what's the difference between them? Does they serve the same purpose?

Answer (score 2):

`LimitAS` and the other limits in `systemd.exec(5)` corresponds to `ulimit`, i. e. the `setrlimit` system call, and is per-process – a process can evade it by forking child processes (the children each inherit the limit, but their memory usage is counted separately). `MemoryLimit` and the other limits in `systemd.resource-control(5)` correspond to cgroup limits and apply to all processes in the control group collectively, which a process cannot escape. You almost certainly want to use those.